# Are birthdays holidays?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, american-english

Are birthdays holidays?

Or if not, is there a general term for all celebration days, including birthdays as well as public holidays (especially in AE).

Festivities? Festival days? Feast days? Revels?

Comment: You said it and it fits: "celebration days".

Comment: do you mean your birthday or other peoples?

Comment: Both. More particularly, family celebrations.

Comment: No  there's no one term that covers both birthdays and holidays. I've never used or heard "celebration days."

Comment: Or commemoration days for those where the term 'celebration' is inappropriate, eg Anzac Day in Aus/NZ.

Comment: @Clare - How about *Red Letter Days*?

Comment: In Australia, the Queen's birthday *is* a (public) holiday, though it's not celebrated on the same day in the whole country. Most people aren't the Queen, though. :)

Comment: Are you including wedding anniversaries, other anniversaries and family celebrations (some couples celebrate the anniversary of their first date or first meeting)? Some companies have a company day e.g. the founder's birthday or anniversary of founding, as a day off work. And what about commemorations - e.g. an annual dinner in honour of a dead friend or relative?

Comment: Are they in your native tongue?? I bet in German they are days of celebration.

Answer (score 7):

**A) Only if you're not going to work.**

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com), which has the lengthiest and most inclusive list of definitions for the word that I could find, the following is the definition for *holiday*:

> 1. a day fixed by law or custom on which ordinary business is suspended in commemoration of some event or in honor of some person.
> 2. any day of exemption from work (distinguished from working day ).
> 3. a time or period of exemption from any requirement, duty, assessment, etc.
> 4. a religious feast day; holy day, especially any of several usually commemorative holy days observed in Judaism.
> 5. Sometimes, holidays. Chiefly British. a period of cessation from work or one of recreation; vacation.

Several other sources offer extremely similar definitions (see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holiday) and [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/holiday)) As you can see, the word *holiday*  is virtually exclusive to days off from work, official or not. Having a birthday does not mean it's a holiday, and if you take the day off, you're *on holiday* or *holidaying* (and though this constitutes a *holiday*, it only applies to that one year, not ones in the past and future). If you don't take the day off, it's not a holiday.

It may be argued that any given day of the year has some kind of holiday or observance; this is correct but semantically I think you meant "is a birthday a holiday in itself"? The answer is no.

So *holidays* do not necessarily encompass *birthdays.* Meanwhile, a *festival* or *celebration* is only a *birthday* if the latter is recognized somehow, but according to [this](http://reversedictionary.org/wordsfor/birthday%20or%20holiday), that's the closest you'll get. Thus, there is no word that will incorporate both holidays and birthdays a hundred percent of the time, but that's just me being a prescriptivist. People *will* understand you if you call a *birthday* a *holiday, festival, celebration*, or *occasion*, so are they necessarily wrong? It's up to you to determine the usage in our fluid and multifaceted language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! And also for linking the reverse dictionary – that site was completely new to me.

Comment: No problem, hope I could help

Comment: Definitely. But I'm still a bit puzzled by the partly contradicting answers of the other users. 

If I may ask these two follow-up questions: What do you think of @aparente001's and Tony's suggestions (»red letter days« / »on high days and holidays«)? And how come some speakers accept »celebration days« (Centaurus), while others consider it inappropriate (Clare)? 

(I'm new here and not yet quite familiar with the rather restrictive commenting rules on SE)

Comment: It is strange to begin an answer with '**A)**', when there is no '**B)**' in it.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), the place where 'birthday' and 'public holiday' intersect is at '**day** (a day assigned to a particular purpose or observance)'. So, as suspected, no, there is no general term for both that would serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer is that birthdays *can* be understood to be holidays, but they aren't considered holidays by all English speakers.

The most relevant answer depends on whether you want to know about standard usage, technical definition, understandability, or something else.

Do all users of English automatically define birthdays as holidays? No. Some do, and some don't.

Can it be logically argued that birthdays fit the definition of holidays? Yes, though logic doesn't dictate common usage.

Is it understandable/acceptable if the word "holidays" is used as if it includes birthdays? It depends on your audience. Some people understand and accept that usage without explanation. Others require an explanation or clarification, and some don't accept that usage at all.

### Technical definitions

The [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/holiday) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holiday) definitions of "holiday" contain nothing that automatically places all birthdays under the umbrella of holidays. They focus on exemption from work or duty, religious days of celebration, and days fixed by law or custom for commemoration of something or someone.

[The entry for "holiday" on OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/holiday_n?tab=meaning_and_use#1456172) appears to potentially support the "birthdays are holidays" usage:

> 2.a.i. a1400– A day on which work, school, and other ordinary activities of a community are suspended, or on which shops, offices,
> etc., are closed; a day dedicated to leisure or recreation. **Later
> also: a day specially dedicated to recognizing or honouring someone or
> something.**
>
> In early use not clearly distinguishable from sense 1, as work and
> other daily activities were ordinarily prohibited or suspended for
> religious reasons. Now **typically** used to refer to a day that has been
> legally or officially designated as a holiday by a government, school,
> business, etc.

The bold is mine and added for emphasis, partly to highlight the idea that "typically" doesn't mean atypical uses are invalid or non-understandable. Also, "specially dedicated" is open to interpretation, since no specific authority or broad recognition seems required by that phrasing.

Using the OED definition, it's plausible to argue that in any context where birthdays are recognized as days for honoring someone, birthdays are holidays. That includes mainstream Western cultures, since they recognize birthdays as special days to honor specific people. Is it the typical usage (according to OED) to include birthdays under holidays? No. But is it a possible, understandable usage? The OED definition doesn't seem to rule it out.

Note that the concept of a holiday may involve suspension of regular daily activities like work, but doesn't appear to require it. For instance, Christmas doesn't stop being a holiday to someone who works on Christmas, but who otherwise considers Christmas a holiday, even a secular one. With that understanding, working on one's birthday shouldn't automatically render it not a holiday.

### Understandability and usage

While not all users of English see birthdays as holidays, some groups are more likely to understand them that way. For example:

Some workplaces offer holiday pay or paid time off for employees' birthdays. Within those workplaces, birthdays are treated like holidays and might be easily understood as such, or even referred to as holidays. Other workplaces have policies that recognize and honor employees' right to take birthdays off, but without pay, which may suggest that birthdays are considered optional holidays.

In specific subcultures and/or spiritualities, the community encourages or recognizes the validity of individually-defined holidays. In these communities, birthdays might be easily understood to be holidays even when they aren't assumed to be holidays. As one example, the principles of LaVeyan Satanism [suggest](https://www.churchofsatan.com/faq-holidays/) that each member of the church may want to consider their birthday a holiday. Also, in the modern Pagan community, many practitioners create their own practices and traditions, so birthdays might be easily understandable as personal holidays even to Pagans who don't practice that way.

These examples don't tell us what percentage of English users defines birthdays as holidays, but they do show that some businesses and groups of people using English see or treat birthdays as holidays, in the sense of special celebration days and/or days that should be taken off work to honor someone or something.

In the interest of gauging everyday usage, I asked eight native English speakers, without context or explanation, whether they think birthdays are holidays. (No one I asked is part of a non-mainstream subculture that officially suggests birthdays are or should be holidays.) Three people said yes, three said no, and two said they can be holidays but don't have to be. That tentatively supports the idea that in usage, the answer to whether birthdays are holidays is neither "No, birthdays are never holidays" nor "Yes, birthdays are definitely holidays." The answer is more like "It depends on who you ask."

#### A word for all celebrations

There's no single commonly used term I'm aware of that includes all celebration days including holidays and birthdays, but "celebration days" as it appears in the original question is an understandable way to say it. "Celebrations" by itself might also work, depending on the context.

Comment: @jsw29 Is there a source for that usage? Many dictionary definitions contain no explicit community requirement. I'm also unsure of whether a proper answer is about standard usage or understandable usage.

Either way, I'm going to edit my answer, since on reflection, I don't think my explanation was clear enough.

Comment: The same could probably be said about Valentine's Day, Mother's Day, Halloween, Guy Fawkes Night, etc. It seems that English lacks a convenient term to unambiguously refer to the days on which people at large perform rituals specific to the day, but are not generally days off work. One way of dealing with that is to stretch the meaning of *holiday* to encompass them. That is a stretch, but as you convincingly argue for *birthday*, it is an intelligible and widely used stretch.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain there is an informal idiomatic expression ***on high days and holidays***.

For example *Unlike the French and the Italians, the English usually only take wine with their meals "on high days and holidays"*.

The informal sense in which it is used means *high days* could well include birthdays, as well any special day where celebrations were in order - eg somebody passed an exam, got appointed to a new job etc.

There are references to the expression from pre-conquest Old English, but one from 2013 is the following:
*One of the tasks delegated to me was..to purchase cakes on colleagues' birthdays and other high days and holidays.
Gloucestershire Echo (Nexis) 24 July*

Comment: It is not obvious that *high days* includes birthdays; an argument is needed to show that it does. My understanding is that *high days* normally stands for the days of religious significance.

Comment: @jsw29 It all depends on the context in which it is said - eg. a mother to her children "We only have chocolates "on high days and holidays" - might well include birthdays. I have edited my answer to indicate that the expression is informal.

Comment: Even after the edit, it is still not "obvious" that *high days* includes birthdays.

Comment: @Greybeard I've extended the final paragraph. Does that make you feel happier?

Comment: A reference is really needed as to the meaning of "high days". In fact there's no reference at all in the answer.